# Is there a list of questions nominated for reopening?

Tags: support

So to reopen a closed question, it needs five reopen votes. Is there a list of pending questions to be reopened or does one stumble upon them by accident and vote for it?

Should I have made it more clear in the new question title that I changed it to confirm with our rules?

Comment: I know which one you mean -- I asked a mod for help, and it was reopened. (Thanks Mark!) Probably not many people noticed it was changed. Usually this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: you can flag the question for attention with moderators in future.  Or post here or in the chat, one of us will more readily spot it then ;)

Comment: Thanks guys, but the question was not just because of my "Sofia question", so I take it there is no list page for this?

Comment: @PeterHahndorf: Not that I know of. The easiest way is, as Mark said, to ping a moderator about this, or to rant in the chat and draw some attention to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

10K users on regular sites, 2k users on beta sites like this, have access to a Tools tab under Review that includes a list of questions with any re-open votes, as well as a list of recently closed questions. Of course, one has to remember to use those abilities...

https://travel.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools

Comment: Thanks Kate, I had hoped for something like that.

Comment: There's also always the `closed:1` search term if you just want to peruse all currently closed questions (especially if you're not yet at the 10k or equivalent level)